# HTML Input Pattern claims mismatch while JavaScript test claims match

Tags: javascript, html, regex, validation, passwords

I am attempting to do a pattern match on a password input and for some reason HTML claims there is a mismatch while JavaScript claims it matches. Testing my RegExp on [regexr.com/7gmmi](https://regexr.com/7gmmi) claims it is a-okay...

What am I missing?

```
<input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password Input" pattern="/^(?!.*(.)\1{1})(?=(.*[\d]){2,})(?=(.*[a-z]){2,})(?=(.*[A-Z]){2,})(?=(.*[\D\W\S]){2,})(?:[\d\w\S]){8,64}$/">
```

```
const patternPass = new RegExp(/^(?!.*(.)\1{1})(?=(.*[\d]){2,})(?=(.*[a-z]){2,})(?=(.*[A-Z]){2,})(?=(.*[\D\W\S]){2,})(?:[\d\w\S]){8,64}$/);

console.log(patternPass.test("FAGX@s#A2dred01sd"));

/// true
```

Comment: Honestly, given the complexity of that regex and the amount of time it would take to debug, I would be inclined to just do a series of simpler checks: does the string have uppercase/lowercase, does it have at least one number, at least one special character etc.

Comment: The provided pattern and the example pattern are not the same.  I suggest reviewing some example patterns.  Also, try _https://regex101.com_, it's slightly better than _regexr_.

Comment: @Reilas I don't know why the Regexp I provided in plain text removed the stars but it did. The Regexp provided in the code is correct.

Comment: A couple notes on your regex: `[\D\W\S]` matches every character, if you wanted nondigits, nonleters and non spaces, you'd need to use something like `[^\d\w\s]`. But remember that \w also matches _.

Comment: Plus, your last part can be simplified to `\S{8,64}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried removing those slashes at the beginning and end of the pattern attribute and testing again?

Comment: That solves it for the HTML pattern, but breaks it for the JS RegExp... How do I get around that?

Comment: Well you lead me to the solution `new RegExp(/pattern/).source` returns the RegExp without the forward slashes so I can apply it to the inputs pattern.